# Preciso omitir a palavra "window" quando chamar uma função do objeto global?

Tags: javascript, estilo-de-codificação

Seguindo as boas práticas, deixando o código de maneira legível para outros devs, o que devo adotar quando chamo métodos do objeto `window`? Omitir ou não?

Alguns exemplos (simples e isolados):

```
const buttonStyles = getComputedStyle(button);
//const buttonStyles = window.getComputedStyle(button);

alert(erroMessage);
//window.alert(erroMessage);

onload(funtion(){});
//window.onload(funtion(){});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso não tem nada de boa prática. Código legível é subjetivo, e só será bom para os outros se estiver fazendo o que eles esperam. Por isso ninguém pode dizer se deve omitir ou não, depende do que a equipe estabeleceu. O que mais vejo é as pessoas omitindo, mas o mais importante é ser consistente.

Se resolver não omitir precisa justificar isso. É porque fica mais claro que são métodos do objeto `window`? Não sei se é um argumento válido porque este é um objeto que todos deveriam saber de cor e entender que eles são deste objeto mesmo não tendo um prefixo indicando assim. É aquela coisa de decorar o óbvio. A legibilidade se daria com objetos que não são padrões.

Comment: Eu acreditava que essa omissão ou não do objeto window tinha relação com boas bráticas, mas não tem.
Obrigado pela resposta, Maniero.

Comment: @FelipeOliveira quase nada tem a ver com boas práticas. Procure aqui no site o que eu falo sobre o assunto.

Comment: Claro! Irei ler. Obrigado mais uma vez.

Answer (score 0):

A utilização de forma evidente tende a ser melhor compreendida, contudo deve-se relevar o que foi definido em equipe, se de fato algo foi definido.

Caso não, ou mesmo em situações gerais, é muito recomendado padronizar o código entre os integrantes da equipe, então como palavra finalmente recomendo fortemente o uso de `Linters` (como o `ESLint` ou `TSLint`, para o `TypeScript` especificamente).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Leandro!